# how to rename directory using a menu

Tags: bash

i am tring to create a menu that can rename a directory i am having an issue as i am using the mv command but im not sure how to ask for two different variables to then rename the directory

```
PS3="Please enter the number of what you would like to do: " 
menu=("Create Directory" "Rename a directory" "Delete a Directory" "Change Directory" "List directories" "exit menu")  
select opt in "${menu[@]}"  
do
    case $opt in
        "Create Directory")
            echo "What do you want to call the directory?" ; read ; mkdir $REPLY ; #works
            ;;
        
    "Rename a directory")
        echo "What directory would you like to rename?" ; read ; echo "What would you like to rename it to?" ; read ; mv $var1 $var2; 
        ;;
        
    "Delete a Directory")
        echo "what directory do you wan tto delete/" ; read ; rmdir $REPLY ; #works
        ;;
        
    "Change Directory")
        echo "What directory do you want to change to? " ; read ; cd $REPLY ; 
        ;;
        
    "List directories")
          ; 
        ;; 
        
    "exit menu")
        break  #works
        ;;
        
esac
```

the rename the directory part is what i need help with.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: you need something like `echo "which?" ;read srcDir ; echo where ; read targDir ; mv "$srrcDir" "$targDir"`. Only test your code on a separate area you set up under `/tmp`. Be sure to test with a dir that has "space" characters , i.e. "My New Directory". Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks this is now working, but it isnt with a space in the new directory but i think thats becasue of mv and how it wants to move it and not rename but it should be fine like this

Comment: Quote all your parameter expansions. (There are some that don't necessarily *need* to be quoted, like `$opt` in the `case` statement, but even quoting that isn't *harmful* like failing to quote a parameter expansion can be.)

Comment: Learn to check you code at https://shellcheck.net . Be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever) as your first line. Good luck.

Comment: Try `dialog/whiptail` to build menus.

Answer (score 1):

The below is the beginning of another script which performs **command line parsing** to fit your needs.

You can easily switch that up to work with manual input (**multiple prompt+read sequences**) to gather the required data for the desired actions.

It shows that you can do nesting of case/condition matching.

The only other suggestion I would make is that you use the discipline of separating **user-interaction code segments** from **action-performing code segments** (as functions).  That approach allows the **flow logic** to be *viewed in concise form*, keeping *action-related complexity* "**encapsulated**" in the function calls.

```
#!/bin/bash
doSample=1
delim=1
pagesFirstUse=0
pagesLastUse=0
doSplit=0
Ph_4_Mode=0
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --sample ) doSample=1 ; shift ;;
        --full ) doSample=0 ; shift ;;
        --first ) pagesFirstUse=$2 ; doSample=0 ; shift ; shift ;;
        --last ) pagesLastUse=$2 ; doSample=0 ; shift ; shift ;;
        --mode )
            case $2 in
                first_line )
                    doSplit=1 ;
                    Ph_4_Mode=1 ;;
                last_line )
                    doSplit=1 ;
                    Ph_4_Mode=2 ;;
                * ) ;;
            esac
            shift ; shift ;;
        --nodelim ) delim=0 ; shift ;;
        * ) echo -e "\n Invalid parameter on the command line.  Only valid options: [ --sample | --full | --first | --last | --mode [first_line|last_line] | --nodelim ].\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly understood, a `read` stores its answer to the variable `REPLY`. If you do 2 *read* in succession, the second one will of course overwrite this variable. As a solution, either save the first reply into a different variable, i.e.

```
read
reply1=$REPLY
read
# $reply1 and $REPLY give you the two replies
```

or provide a different variable name after the *read*:

```
read
read reply2
# $REPLY and $reply2 give you the two replies
```

Side note:

My recommendation would be to **always** provide an explicit variable name when using `read`. It is less error-prone and better for readability. Laziness is often a virtue, but not always!